# Custom rule validation not working in Yii2 Contact Form extends Model

Tags: php, forms, validation, yii2

I'm creating a website using Yii2. There is a model called Contact Form like this:

```
class ContactForm extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $subject;
    public $body;
    public $response;
    public $response2;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'email', 'subject', 'body'], 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['response', function ($attribute, $params)
            {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Wrong response 1');
            },  'skipOnError' => false],
            ['response2', 'validresponse2'],
        ];
    }

    public function validresponse2($attribute, $params) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Wrong response 2');
    }
}
```

There are 2 attributes (response and response2) which have custom validation.

Both custom validation are not working. They didn't pop up an error message at all. When I put echo "asd; die(); inside those functions, They didn't die too.

Is my rule setting wrong? I've searched through other questions but no luck.

**UPDATE**

Here is how I validate the form in my controller

```
$model = new ContactForm();
$model->subject = "New Message";

if (isset($_POST['ContactForm'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['ContactForm'];
    $model->response = "";
    if ($model->validate()) {
        echo "validated successfully";
        die();
    }
}
```

And it is always validated successfully

Comment: Are you expecting this to work on client side or server side? Because it won't work on client side.

Comment: It's server side, I've set enableClientValidation to false in ActiveForm

Comment: And have you got fields for these attributes in the form so messages can be displayed? If so - ActiveFields or just HTML input tags?

Comment: It was initially for google recaptcha response, I've just tested it by replacing 'response' with 'body' which has textarea field and remove 'body' from 'required' section. But then, 'body' doesn't pop up any error message just like 'response'. Here's the screenshot: http://take.ms/eVIvD

Comment: I added new lines on how I validate the form in my controller.

Comment: So you replaced 'response' with 'body' in validation rules and then setting `$model->response = "";`? There is no rule for `response` now.

Comment: The reason I replace 'response' with 'body' is just to tell you that despite having field, the custom validation for 'body' is also not working. After that, I changed the code back to original

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131894/discussion-between-bizley-and-henry-gunawan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `skipOnError` you need to set `skipOnEmpty` to `false` because otherwise empty attribute does not trigger validation.

`skipOnError` is `true` by default and means that in case of validation error in one rule the rest of rules for this attribute are skipped.